# faster way to fetch the data from postgresql in python

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, pandas, postgresql

Important column database:

| script_id | date_time |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-01-11 09:35:00 |
| 1 | 2019-01-11 09:40:00 |
| 1 | 2019-01-11 09:45:00 |
| 2 | 2019-01-11 09:35:00 |
| 2 | 2019-01-11 09:40:00 |
| 2 | 2019-01-11 09:45:00 |

Like this I am having 900K+ rows (1st Jan'19 to 30th June'21)

I am having only 200 unique  script_id, so each date_time will also be repeated 200 times.

Full column database:

[image: database]

Now, I tried to execute the below code

```
df = pd.DataFrame(db_fetchquery("SELECT script_id,date_time,open,high,low,close,volume FROM data_five_minutes WHERE date_time >= '2019-01-11 09:35:00' and date_time <= '2019-01-11 09:50:00' ORDER BY id"))
df.columns = ['script_id','date_time','open','high','low','close','volume']

print(df)
```

This gave me result in approximately 143 seconds

[image: result]

How can I fetch the data more quickly (at-least within 30 seconds)

Comment: Are you able to reduce the amount of data you are requesting from the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT script_id,date_time,open,high,low,close,volume
FROM data_five_minutes
WHERE date_time >= '2019-01-11 09:35:00' and date_time <= '2019-01-11 09:50:00'
ORDER BY id
```

You want an index on `data_five_minutes(date_time)`.  In the database you create the index using:

```
create index idx_data_five_minutes_date_tinme on data_five_minutes(date_time);
```

Comment: This really helped, on first run it took 20s and on next two less than **3** s and then after 10 mins I ran one more time (with different year/date/time) and it took only **3s**, wow! Can you advise why it took more time on first run. and if you see database it will have new rows on daily basis ( i assume 75K), so shall I need to create index on daily basis?

Comment: @Kabomi . . . This is probably due to what is called a *cold cache*.  The index needs to be loaded into memory.  After that, it tends to stick around.

Comment: database it will have new rows on daily basis ( i assume 75K), so shall I need to create index on daily basis or it will be update automatically?

Comment: @Kabomi . . . You only need to create the index once.  It is updated when new rows are inserted.  Although index updates do impose overhead, at a rate of less than 1 per second, you should be fine.

Comment: what will be quick `WHERE date_time >= '2019-01-11 09:35:00' and date_time <= '2019-01-11 09:50:00'` **OR** `WHERE date_time BETWEEN ('2019-01-11 09:35:00' and '2019-01-11 09:50:00')`?

Comment: @Kabomi . . . I think it would be hard to measure the difference between the two.  That said, `BETWEEN` doesn't use parentheses so the second option should generate a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can optimize database query

1. Add index on `date_time` column (with desc if you're going to query most recent data first)
2. Do `explain analyse` your query to check what is taking long to respond.
3. If your table is having large data then use [table partitions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/ddl-partitioning.html). It will make divide table in small partitions based on your partition column. By which each query will have to read less data
4. Use raw query if possible. ORM is slower when your query result has the high number of returned rows because ORM need to map each column to model.

Comment: 1) somewhat like this: `create index idx_data_five_minutes_date_tinme on data_five_minutes(date_time) order by date_time desc;`?

Comment: 4) raw query, could you please advise what exactly?

Comment: database internally respond with raw data. Your ORM (SQLAlchemy maybe in this case) map it to your Model and you get resultProxy in the response. This takes time if your data is very huge

Try using psycopg2, with which you can run raw query, It's faster compared to ORM

Comment: okay any update for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68846280/faster-way-to-fetch-the-data-from-postgresql-in-python#comment121676649_68846624 ?